# Creating a javascript object and binding this

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build my first node app. My app.js file is shown below. I want to access this from aother module by doing 'app = require('app')'. I then want to access app.app, app.dbConn and app.models

The problem is that when I require this module, app.models is not present on the resulting object.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var orm = require('orm');

var settings = require('./config/settings');
var mainRouter = require('./config/routes');
var environment = require('./config/environment');
var db = require('./config/db');
var auth = require('./modules/auth');

module.exports = new function(){
    this.app = express();

    // middlewares must be added in order - start with the basics
    environment(this.app);
    if (process.env.TESTING) { dbSettings = settings.dbTesting; }
    else { dbSettings = settings.db; }

    // add models to the request early in the middleware chain
    this.dbConn = orm.connect(dbSettings, function(err){
      if (err) return console.error('DB Connection error: ' + err);
      else{
        this.models = db.init(this.dbConn);
        this.app.use(function(req,res,next){
          req.models = this.models;
          next();
        });

        passport = auth.init(this.models);
        authRouter = auth.router(passport)

        this.app.use('/users', authRouter);
        this.app.use(mainRouter);
      }
    }.bind(this));
    this.app.listen(settings.port);
    console.log('Server started... listening on port ' + settings.port)
}
```

The only way to implement what I wanted was with a function that takes a callback, in the end I rewrote my code thus:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var orm = require('orm');

var settings = require('./config/settings');
var mainRouter = require('./config/routes');
var environment = require('./config/environment');
var db = require('./config/db');
var auth = require('./modules/auth');

var app;

module.exports = function(cb){
  app = express();

  // middlewares must be added in order - start with the basics
  environment(app);
  if (process.env.TESTING) { dbSettings = settings.dbTesting; }
  else { dbSettings = settings.db; }

  // add models to the request early in the middleware chain
  dbConn = orm.connect(dbSettings, function(err){
    if (err) return console.error('DB Connection error: ' + err);
    else{
      models = db.init(dbConn);
      app.use(function(req,res,next){
        req.models = models;
        next();
      });

      passport = auth.init(this.models);
      authRouter = auth.router(passport)

      app.use('/users', authRouter);
      app.use(mainRouter);

      cb({
        dbConn: dbConn,
        app: app,
        models: models
      });
    }
  });
}

if (!process.env.TESTING) {
  module.exports(function(server){
    server.app.listen(settings.port);
    console.log('Server started... listening on port ' + settings.port)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.models` is defined only once database connection is completed: you cannot use it right away after requiring the module. You should provide an entry point that accepts a function to call once the connection is ready and call this function inside the `orm.connect` callback.

Even the "server started" message is a bit misleading as it's shown **before** the server can actually do anything because the function passed to `orm.connect` has not been called yet.

Answer (score 0):

app.models is never defined so it is never available.

Instead, try

```
app.set('models', db.init(this.dbConn);
```